# Use mongoDB $lookup to find documents in another collection not present inside an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

I'm using the aggregate framework to query a collection and create an array of active players (up until the last `$lookup`) after which I'm trying to use `$lookup` and `$pipeline` to select all the players from another collection (`users`) that are ***not*** present inside the `activeUsers` array.

Is there any way of doing this with my current setup?

```js
Game.aggregate[{
  $match: {
    date: {
      $gte: ISODate('2021-04-10T00:00:00.355Z')
    },
    gameStatus: 'played'
  }
}, {
  $unwind: {
    path: '$players',
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
  }
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: '$players'
  }
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    activeUsers: {
      $push: '$_id'
    }
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    activeUsers: true,
    _id: false
  }
}, {
  $lookup: {
    from: 'users',
    'let': {
      active: '$activeUsers'
    },
    pipeline: [{
        $match: {
          deactivated: false,
          // The rest of the query works fine but here I would like to 
          // select only the elements that *aren't* inside
          // the array (instead of the ones that *are* inside)
          // but if I use '$nin' here mongoDB throws 
          // an 'unrecognized' error 
          $expr: {
            $in: [
              '$_id',
              '$$active'
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 1
        }
      }
    ],
    as: 'users'
  }
}]
```

Thanks

Comment: just use `$not` like this `{ $expr: { $not: { $in: ['$_id', '$$active'] } } }`

Comment: Please add your your comment as an answer so I can select it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For negative condition use `$not` before `$in` operator,

```
{ $expr: { $not: { $in: ['$_id', '$$active'] } } }
```